# Scrape data from dbpedia in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, dbpedia

I want to search persons in dbpedia and scrape some information like biography, state and an image. I find some ways to scrape data for example using Goutte ( https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte ). But i want to know if there is a better and simple way to do it.

Comment: That's the best way I know.

Comment: DBpedia already provides structured data, why bother scraping? Did you try the SPARQL endpoint of the downloading the dumps?
see http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess